# Installing a binary to the PATH of a Google Composer worker node

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have an Apache Airflow workflow which needs a 3rd party binary to be installed on the worker node that runs the airflow.

To do this, I followed the following steps:

1. SSH into the worker instance
2. Downloaded and extracted the binary
3. Set the required environment variables and updated the `PATH` variable in the `.bash_profile` file available in my home directory as below:

   `export HIVE_HOME=/home/sagunawardhana_virtusa_com/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin`
   `PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin`

When I try to execute the binary `beeline` in a shell (which is available in the directory `$HIVE_HOME/bin`) I get the following error:

```
-bash: /home/mygmailaccount/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/bin/beeline: Permission denied
```

All sufficient permissions have been granted to the relevant binary including `chmod +x $HIVE_HOME/bin/beeline`

I want this executable to be available to the account that runs my workflow

Comment: Hi ! How did you end you solving this?